# Materialize CSS Modal not working with Vue

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I am trying to use materialize modal in Vue..

I have imported it in **main.js**

```
import 'materialize-css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js'
```

**File.vue**

```
<a class="fa fa-trash modal-trigger" href="#delete" @click="consolel(index)"></a>

        <div id="delete" class="modal" ref="deleteModal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Modal Header</h4>
            <p>A bunch of text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a
              href="#!"
              class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat"
              @click="deleteItem(index)"
            >Agree</a>
          </div>
        </div>

mounted(){
     M.AutoInit();
}
```

I tried the way, docs asked to trigger modal

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
});
```

In **mounted**.
But this didn't work.

**How to trigger modal in Vue?!**

Comment: share the full code in a snippet please, including the importations please

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to simply pass an array of `vue references` and derive the underlying Node from the VNode.

```
M.Modal.init([this.$refs['deleteModal'][0]], null)
```

Comment: It says this.$refs.deleteModal[0]] is not defined

Comment: @user11024704 Try it with the array accessor method. Updated.

Comment: There is no error.. I just keep clicking and nothing happens